# getHibernateTemplate().find() over many-to-many association

Tags: spring, hibernate

In the following scenario, of a **many-to-many** association, what is the proper query to pass to the **getHibernateTemplate().find()** method, in order to get the list of events (and persons) for the events that have participants?

```
    _____________        __________________
   |             |      |                  |       _____________
   |   EVENTS    |      |   PERSON_EVENT   |      |             |
   |_____________|      |__________________|      |    PERSON   |
   |             |      |                  |      |_____________|
   | *EVENT_ID   | <--> | *EVENT_ID        |      |             |
   |  EVENT_DATE |      | *PERSON_ID       | <--> | *PERSON_ID  |
   |  TITLE      |      |__________________|      |  AGE        |
   |_____________|                                |  FIRSTNAME  |
                                                  |  LASTNAME   |
                                                  |_____________|



<class name="Event" table="EVENTS">
    <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>   
    <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
    <property name="title"/>

    <set name="participants" table="PERSON_EVENT">
        <key column="EVENT_ID"/>
        <many-to-many column="PERSON_ID" class="Person"/>
    </set>      
</class>


<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
    <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="age"/>
    <property name="firstname"/>
    <property name="lastname"/>

    <set name="events" table="PERSON_EVENT" inverse="true">
        <key column="PERSON_ID"/>
        <many-to-many column="EVENT_ID" class="Event"/>
    </set>

</class>
```

Several attempts like this one fail with following exceptions:

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from Event event where event.participants != null");
```

*org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException etc etc etc
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
etc etc*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the same result.

from Event event where event.participants is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Ram Reddy suggested query worked, but I need to add lazy="false":

```
<set name="participants" table="PERSON_EVENT" lazy="false">
        <key column="EVENT_ID"/>
        <many-to-many column="PERSON_ID" class="Person"/>
</set>
```